# constructor with std::move without passing by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-semantics

I sometimes encounter the following type of constructor.

```cpp
struct A
{
    std::string a; 
    A( std::string a ) : a( std::move(a) ){ }  \\ a is not passed by reference
};
```

Something confusing to me is that, it seems that `a` is not passed by the reference, thus a copy of `a` is made. And if so, this is nonsense to do `std::move`. But many experts seem to do this, so there must be reason behind that. Could you explain why?

Comment: `a(a)` would be an *additional* copy, `a(std::move(a))` is just a (presumably cheap) move.

Comment: `a(std::move(a))` does make sense to me. But, I wonder why people don't do  `A(std::string& a) : a(std::move(a)) {}` .

Comment: Suppose I have `std::string str("my string"); A a(str);`. After that line, `str` will become empty. Does it make sense? I guess, no. I would not expect `A a(str);` to modify `str`. When you take `std::string` by value, you could be explicit about your intention: `A a(std::move(str));`. Now it is reasonable that `str` becomes empty.

Answer (score 0):

It avoids a second copy. Otherwise, constructing the local `std::string` from the `std::string` passed to the function would be a second copy.